# How to find total(sum) in mysql from alias?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Actually i have the original database as

```
SELECT sum(data1,data2) as database_value,sum(data3,data4) as database_not_value  from table_name;

| ID | science_name_short    |database_value   | database_not_value| 
|  1 | Rhododendron phipli   |3                | 4                 |  
|  2 | Rhododendron felica   |5                |6                  |  
| 3  | Rhododendron deron    |5                | 7                 |   
| 4  | Rhododendron  sednuns |5                |8                  |
```

and i want to find the total of first rows,2nd rows,3rd rows and show them in total column so i did

```
SELECT sum(data1,data2) as database_value,sum(data3,data4) as database_not_value,sum(database_value+database_not_value) as total
  from table_name;

| ID |     science_name_short    |database_value   | database_not_value|Total | 
|  1 | Rhododendron phipli       |3                | 4                 |   7  |
|  2 | Rhododendron felica       |5                |6                  |   11 |
|3   | Rhododendron deron        |5                | 7                 |   12 |
|4   | Rhododendron  sednuns     |5                |8                  |   13 |



 then i get error as column "database_value" does not exist
```

Comment: This query cannot produce that result

Comment: And, plainly, that is not your 'original' data

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I didn't know that `SUM` can take a CSV list of arguments in MySQL.  Oh wait, [it can't](http://rextester.com/EYYL31125).

Comment: Give us something to look at (like an SQL fiddle), may be we could help..

Comment: unless you return your first script as a table(or temporary table) you wont be able to treat alias name as field. so just repeat your code to sum all 4 fields in total....(if SUM can do that )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use alias at same level of query, To get total you need to repeat your expression

```
SELECT sum(data1 + data2) as database_value,
sum(data3 + data4) as database_not_value,
sum(data1 + data2) + sum(data3+ data4)  as total
from table_name;
```

also `sum()` takes single argument  so i assume you are adding your data sets using `+` not by comma

Comment: thnk u khalid  :)